# KQL remove from the output strings which have a duplicated value in one of the columns

Tags: kql

Let's say I have a table with records about users who had passed certain doors.

I want to remove from the output all strings with records about users that passed 1st door if there is a record about them passing the 2nd door.

`summarise by distinct` could not be used because I need to keep `Timestamp`.
[image]

PS In reality, the event registration time differs by thousandths of a second. That's I don't want to use only the later events. It seems to me more correct is to leave only the record with an event of the first type if there is an event of the second type.

Comment: In other words, you are looking for the last record per Name?

Comment: edited my initial post

Comment: So `Timestamp` has nothing to do with the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datatable(Name:string,Source:string,Timestamp:timespan)
[
    'Jack', '1StDoor', '1:01'
   ,'Jill', '1StDoor', '1:02'
   ,'Jill', '2ndDoor', '1:03'
   ,'Mike', '1StDoor', '1:04'
   ,'John', '1StDoor', '1:05'
   ,'John', '2ndDoor', '1:06'
]
| summarize arg_max(Source, *) by Name
```

| Name | Source | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 1StDoor | 01:01:00 |
| Jill | 2ndDoor | 01:03:00 |
| Mike | 1StDoor | 01:04:00 |
| John | 2ndDoor | 01:06:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUDb/E3FSr4pKizLx0neD80qJkOC8kMze1uCQxt8CqBMQqSMzT5OWK5uXiVPdKTM5W1%20FUNwwuccnPL1LXUVA3tDIwVOflUlBQ0FH3yszJwZQ2Qpc2yktBkjaGSftmZqdi6jaB687PyMOUNkWXRjXcDCgdy8tVo1BcmpubWJRZlaqQWJQen5tYoQHxs46ClqZCUqUCKDQAkBg2DRwBAAA=)